# Notepad++ 7.8.5 doesnt have launch in chrome under Run

Tags: notepad++

I am doing a beginner Udemy course on Web development  and installed Notepad++.
When I wanted to Run my 1st exercise by Launching in Chrome, this "Launch in Chrome" is not under the Run menu in Notepadd++. I searched Google for the problem and found this below, but as a beginner, I do not quite understand how to fix the problem.

This is the possible solution I have found, but I am still not getting it right.

> The Run Menu usually contains the Launch in Firefox/Chrome/IE/Edge entries.
>
> They are defined in the shortcuts.xml configuration file. If you have a normally-installed Notepad++, you can edit them at %AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml; if it’s a portable, or any installation that doesn’t use AppData, it will be in the same directory as notepad++.exe itself. A caveat for editing that file: exit all instances of Notepad++ (to make sure all settings are saved); then open Notepad++ and edit the shortcuts.xml file, save and exit Notepad++. The next time you open Notepad++, the changes will have taken effect.

So, combining the advice from both posts:

```
<UserDefinedCommands>
    <Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">firefox "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"</Command>
    <Command name="Launch in IE" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="73">iexplore "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"</Command>
    <Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"</Command>...
    <Command name="Launch in Edge" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="69"> shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)</Command>
```

(There may be other entries in the  section before or after these; I just included the start-tag to tell you where in the file to add the launch-in-browser commands)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you work under Windows. Press the key combination <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `%appdata%`. Navigate down to Notepad++. Check if there is a section `<UserDefinedCommands>` in the file **shortcuts.xml**.

Please check and insert the following line if required. Please note it is better to use `&quot;` instead of **"** for the `XMLNode.value` of the `<Command>`node.

```
<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="81">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

BTW - this is the line I copied form my Notepad++ 7.8.5 without having the problem you described. Normally this all is installed by default.

If you changed the file **shortcut.xml** manually, incorrect XML may have occurred.

A quick test can be performed by simply dragging the file from Windows Explorer onto an open EDGE window as shown in the screenshot below for test case only. Of course, no error message should appear!

[image]